# Triggering a shell script from MySQL without any 3rd party libraries

Tags: mysql, trigger

Is it possible to call a bash script file in linux using a trigger in MySQL?
I've been searching for the answer online and I ran into this articles:

http://patternbuffer.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/triggering-shell-script-from-mysql/

http://crazytechthoughts.blogspot.com/2011/12/call-external-program-from-mysql.html?showComment=1416010000049#c2028082587789719436

But I was wondering if it's possible to do it without any 3rd party libraries like UDF for example. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing native unless using the MySQL Client where you can issue \! {shell command}.

e.g.

```
mysql> \! pwd
/home/moore
```